# Whom and who in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses, whom

I'm struggling to wrap my brain around this and would appreciate some advice please.

Are there situations where it is appropriate to use **Who** immediately after **Whom**?

Here's my example from a story I'm writing (the text is from a faux historian)

> While one can understand the actions of a lonely few – some of **whom
>   who** perhaps did make good their escape...

When I try it with just the whom it sounds wrong. I'm unsure if I'm just getting super confused with tenses here but this is the second time I've tried to word a sentence like this and its annoying me that I can't get it right. Previously I just ended up reworking it to avoid the issue altogether, but I feel it should be possible to construct in this way.

In my head if I was saying this as an aside in conversation right now, I might say:

> some of them who perhaps did make good on their escape...

So is it ok to substitute **them** with **whom**?

Suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: I don't understand what the sentence is trying to say, could you care to elaborate? But generally no, you can only use either. In this case the pronoun "one" is being used indefinitely and the expression is quite formal, so I'd retain whom and take out who. As for the second part, **them** is only used if you are referring to specific people (a group); but every individual in the group does not have to be known.

Comment: Interesting thanks. It's supposed to be a clarification from the author that some of the 'lonely few' potentially did escape an island beset by disease - does that help?

Comment: Google Books claims 1,600,000 written instances of [*some of **whom** were*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22some+of+whom+were%22). They've also got  28,700 instances of [*some of **who** were*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22some+of+who+were%22) (mostly, *later*, since the modern trend is to replace ***whom*** by ***who*** in many if not all contexts), and 1,210 instances of [*some of **whom who** were*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22some+of+whom+who+were%22) (mostly *older*; I doubt many would consider using it today).

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. I tried googling whom who in quotes to see if it was used together but it just turned up lots of sites going into when you would use either. That it has been used in older works might means it achieves the general vibe I'm going for, so thank you

Comment: I mean: "some of whom made good their escape". But I'd like to express the author's uncertainty (hence the 'who perhaps'). He's assuming some escaped but allows that this is purely speculation. I take the point it's poorly worded but I'm trying to recreate slightly clunky wording I imagine this historian would use, specifically while he's prepared to offer personal comment, he's careful not to present as fact something he has no evidence to support.

Comment: "… some of whom—perhaps those who were actually aliens—made their escape…"

Comment: thinking about it, would a simple comma achieve what I'm looking for and help the reader understand the meaning: "some of whom, who perhaps did make good on their escape. I could also have a comma after perhaps...

Comment: ...the actions of a lonely few – *those* who perhaps **managed** to escape...

Answer (score 3):

In this context, you don’t need the “who”. You can use pied-piping, putting the prepositional phrase “of whom” at the start of the relative clause:

> While one can understand the actions of a lonely few – of whom some perhaps did make good their escape...

For the more general question, the earlier question [Who/whom + who relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321991/who-whom-who-relative-clause) may be relevant.

Answer (score -1):

There is something called OBLIGATORY "whom" which is used after a preceeding quantifiers i.e: some of, few of, both of, all of, etc. So if you find one of them, you are obligated to use "whom" afterwards. 
Ex: There are many sudents who will graduate next month. Some of whom may receive honorary degree because of their exellency.
So, no matter how weird they sound, you are obliged to use it as above. That's why they named it "obligatory whom"

But you are free to use 'them' or 'whom' in the end. Not many ppl use whom these days but if you wanna make it formal, then you might want to use 'whom' instead.